# How to model this website requirement

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have to design a website which allow a user to make a customize form. Later this form is share to other users.

User ( creator of form ) can pick elements like "`input box`" , "`check box`" or "`date`" etc. Each element would have a set of validations like for "input box" , user can select "`alphanumeric`" or "`only digits`" or "`not empty`" etc. These validations can be more complex.

Then the forms is shared with other users ( receiver of form ). They fill their values in the form.

User receive the form should face the same validations for each field like set by owner of form.

My challenge is how to store and create javascript for validations dynamically ?

If it is simple elements then I could have stored complete HTML and render it on display but here validations come into picture.

Any idea on how to achieve this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: You should check out parselyjs if you are using Jquery.  http://parsleyjs.org/    This might give you some more insight on the validation.  The validation would be stored on the HTML.  Always do validation on the server as well as you can't always trust the client.  Which can be achieved by having a JSON object with the fields and validation required for those fields.

Comment: @Jordan : Thanks Man , Let me see parsley.js

Comment: @Jordan : I come to know my team member is using bootstrap validator . Anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to define a pseudo class:

```
function Validator(args){
    this.type = args.type || 'object';
    this.max = args.max || null;
    this.min = args.min || null;
    this.canBeEmpty = args.empty || false;
    this.validate = function(input) {
        var bool = true; //this is going to be true/false for valid/invalid
        if ((typeof(input) != this.type) || (!this.canBeEmpty && input === '')) {
            bool = false;
        } else {
            if (this.type == 'number') {
                //test against min/max
            }
        }
        return bool;
    }
}

var myFormValidator = new Validator(); //optionally add necessary arguments
var element = document.getElementById(/*input element id*/);
element.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var value = element.value; //or text, or whatever is appropriate
    var valid = myFormValidator.validate(value);
    if (valid) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //do other stuff
    }
});
```

You could substitute a factory function or a closure if that's more your style than the above constructor.

Comment: My Team member is using bootstrap validator. Anyways thanks for your answer.